# PKCS#11 Soft Token for supporting symmetric function

Tags: aes, des, encryption-symmetric, pkcs#11

For testing my codes, I need a PKCS#11 soft token which support symmetric functions like AES, DES, ...
Which PKCS#11 soft token support at least one symmetric function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found OpenCryptokey:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/s-pkcs/

This Soft Token has symmetric functions.